# Gauss Method using parallelism in C++

Tags: c++, asynchronous, parallel-processing, gaussian

I need some help with understanding of parallel computing in c++.
I've wrote classic implementation of [Gauss method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) for solving linear equations:

```
int Gauss::Solve(SimpleGraph<double> matr, std::vector<double>& answer) {
  const int n = matr.get_rows();
  const int m = matr.get_cols() - 1;

  // straight way
  std::vector<int> where(m, -1);
  for (int row = 0, col = 0; row < n && col < m; ++col) {
    // pivot searching
      try {
        matr.SwapRows(row, FindPivotRow(matr, row, col));
      } catch (...) {
        continue;
      }
      where[col] = row;

      // making triangle matrix
    for (int i = row + 1; i != n; ++i) {
      auto coef = matr[i][col] / matr[row][col];
      for (int j = col; j <= m; ++j) {
        matr[i][j] -= matr[row][j] * coef;
        if (std::abs(matr[i][j]) < EPS) matr[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
    ++row;
  }

  // way back
  answer.assign(m, 0);
  for (int row = n - 1; row >= 0; --row) {
    // check sum of coefs near 'x'
    double sum = 0;
    for (int col = m - 1; col >= 0; --col)
      sum += matr[row][col];

    if (std::abs(sum) < EPS && std::abs(matr[row][m]) > EPS) {
      return NONE;
    }

    // works because matrix is triangle now
    for (int col = m; col >= row /* 0 */; --col)
      matr[row][col] /= matr[row][row];

    // making diagonal matrix
    for (int i = row - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      double K = matr[i][row] / matr[row][row];
      for (int j = m; j >= 0; --j) {
        matr[i][j] = matr[i][j] - matr[row][j] * K;
      }
    }

  }

  // here we have diagonal main matrix, so answers are free members

  for (int i = 0; i != m; ++i)
    if (where[i] == -1) return LOT;


  for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
    answer[i] = matr[i][n];
  }

  return ONE;
}
```

Method returns `ONE` if there are only one solution, `NONE` if no solution exists, and `LOT` if there are a lot of solutions.

`SimpleGraph` is just a wrapper around vector with overloaded `operator[]`.

Function `FindPivotRow` throws exception if there are no pivot element under current row and pivot element is zero --> so we can continue from next row.

I need to integrate parallel computing here using `std::thread` and `std::mutex`. I know that the main idea of threads is to do independent calculations in different threads.
As Gauss method has 2 main parts (2 ways), I tried to make them parallel:

```
struct StraightWay {
  SimpleGraph<double>& matr_ref;
  std::vector<int>& where_ref;
  std::mutex& matr_mtx_ref;

  void operator()(int n, int m) {
    matr_mtx_ref.lock();
    for (int row = 0, col = 0; row < n && col < m; ++col) {
      try {
        matr_ref.SwapRows(row, FindPivotRow(matr_ref, row, col));
      } catch (...) {
        continue;
      }
      where_ref[col] = row;

      for (int i = row + 1; i != n; ++i) {
        double coef = matr_ref[i][col] / matr_ref[row][col];
        for (int j = 0; j <= m; ++j) {
          matr_ref[i][j] -= matr_ref[row][j] * coef;

          if (std::abs(matr_ref[i][j]) < Gauss::EPS) matr_ref[i][j] = 0;
        }
      }
      ++row;
    }
    matr_mtx_ref.unlock();
  }

};

struct BackwardWay {
  SimpleGraph<double>& matr_ref;
  std::mutex& matr_mtx_ref;

  void operator()(int n, int m) {

    matr_mtx_ref.lock();
    for (int row = n - 1; row >= 0; --row) {
      double sum = 0;
      for (int col = m - 1; col >= 0; --col)
        sum += matr_ref[row][col];

      if (std::abs(sum) < Gauss::EPS && std::abs(matr_ref[row][m]) > Gauss::EPS) {
        /* idk what to do here */
        /* return NONE; */
      }

      for (int col = m; col >= row /* 0 */; --col)
        matr_ref[row][col] /= matr_ref[row][row];

      for (int i = row - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        double K = matr_ref[i][row] / matr_ref[row][row];
        for (int j = m; j >= 0; --j) {
          matr_ref[i][j] = matr_ref[i][j] - matr_ref[row][j] * K;
        }
      }
    }
    matr_mtx_ref.unlock();

  }
};

int Gauss::ParallelSolve(SimpleGraph<double> matr, std::vector<double>& answer) {
  const int n = matr.get_rows();
  const int m = matr.get_cols() - 1;

  std::mutex matr_mtx;

  std::vector<int> where(m, -1);

  StraightWay strw{matr, where, matr_mtx};
  BackwardWay bckw{matr, matr_mtx};

  std::thread straight_way(strw, n, m);
  std::thread backward_way(bckw, n, m);

  straight_way.join();
  backward_way.join();

  for (int i = 0; i != m; ++i)
    if (where[i] == -1) return LOT;

  answer.assign(n, 0);
  for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
    answer[i] = matr[i][n];
  }

  return ONE;
}
```

So, struct `StraigthWay` is a copy of the first part of classic implementation, and struct `BackwardWay` is the same as the second part of classic solution.

`std::mutex matr_mtx` doesn't allow to change 'matr' at the same time from different threads.

As a result, the execution time for classic solution is much better than the parallel one.

When deleting `mutex`, the answer is wrong (ofc) but the exec time is good.
I think when I create a critical zone with mutex, it is just copies the behavior of classic solution and waste resources on creating threads and their processing.

My main question is **How to make gauss algorithm parallel?**

Comment: You don't, gauss method is strictly sequential, you have to use other methods like newton method or jacobi

Comment: @AhmedAEK I don't think so. It seems fine to parallelize the `i`-based loop so to update lines independently.

Comment: I think the main issue is that you parallelize the wrong loop. The loop you tried to parallelize is inherently sequential. Swapping the pivot in parallel causes a race condition (such thing not only cause the code to have an undefined behaviour, that is, likely wrong results, but also often decrease performance, which is the least of your problem with wrong results).

Comment: Parallelizing the `i`-based loop will speed things up, and be I think correct. But you should not expect a big performance improvement : the code should be mainly memory-bound when compiler optimizations are enabled.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I did that, but i can't improve the execution time. With parallel loops execution time increased a lot

Comment: I am confused. Correctness matters more than performance. A code doing nothing is very fast but wrong ;) . Thus, you should use a correct parallelisation method, and then try to understand why it is not faster, typically by profiling the code (you can then report things here if you want some help about this). As I said, if the code is memory bound, then parallelism may not worth it. Tiling may help to make the operation less memory bound but the benefit will certainly be small and I think it will not be trivial to do here (if even possible).

Comment: @JérômeRichard I've just edited my post. Now it is more understandable.